# Python scripts in HTML

Tags: python, html

Is it possible to write `Python` scripts in HTML code similarly as you write PHP between `<?php ... ?>` tags?

I'd like to achieve that my `Python` application will run in the browser.

thank you for help

Comment: Also see [Best way to integrate Python code with HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7916244/418413)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP doesn't run in the browser, as it is a server side language. You could try [Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/) to try to run python in the browser.

Answer (score 8):

Python indentation requirements don't go well with mixing HTML and Python code. Therefore, the most prominent method (which is a framework called [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/)), uses a template engine so that the Python is never in direct contact with the HTML code.

It will be similar to PHP and not javascript, as it will run on the server-side.

There is also [mod_python](http://www.modpython.org/) for Apache, but I would strongly recommend using Django, which also runs on an Apache server.

Comment: Django is similar as CMS? Can it exist simultaneously with my Drupal installation?

Comment: @xralf Django does make it easy to create CMS systems, but it's not a CMS system per se. And yes, you can still keep PHP/Drupal on the server and use it separately from Django.

Comment: Indentation is the one thing about Python that I like the least.  If the indentation is the main reason why Python hasn't been embedded in HTML, then that gives me even more reason to dislike it.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up client-side and server-side execution of code.

Browsers support only Javascript.

Any application-server or Python-based webframework support template language where you can mix HTML and Python in some way or the other.

Comment: >> You are mixing up client-side and server-side execution of code. ... It was my intension to name one server-side and one client-side scripting language, because I didn't know exactly what I want, but it seems that client side is for my purpose more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

A newer answer for an older question:  There is a Python framework called [Karrigell](http://karrigell.sourceforge.net/) that
supports what it calls "[Python Inside HTML](http://karrigell.sourceforge.net/en/pythoninsidehtml.html)".  It interprets Python from HTML files with a "`.pih`" extension.

I've not tried Karrigell, but it looks compelling.

Answer (score -1):

Well, this might be overkill, but you can install a localhost xampp server. Then, just put the right comments at the top of the file to direct xampp to the interpreter, and you can print out html or regular words right from the language itself. For example, a Python script like this

```
#!/Python34/python

print "Content-type: text/html"
print

print "Hello World"
```

Would give a webpage saying Hello World

Comment: xampp works with php, perl, and almost any scripting language out there