# How to release pygame into a webpage

Tags: python, pygame, html

So I made a game in pygame, and I have no programming experience in Java or Html. Is there anyway that I can release it on a webpage. I have searched this on google but no clear answer was available. Also is there any web page maker website that you can run pygame and python on to display? Weebly doesn't seem to work, webstarts, etc... Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use Pygbag the pygame wasm packager you can find on PyPI https://pypi.org/project/pygbag/

Answer (score -1):

Although Python and HTML are quite separate, you can try using [Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/). 
Similar question asked here: [Python scripts in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842487/python-scripts-in-html)

Comment: Yeah, I think it does

Comment: Wish there was a easier way of doing this.