# Is it possible to put pygame on html and css?

Tags: html, css, pygame

I am making a website using html and CSS. I am using pygame and planning to put it on my website, but I couldn't find anyway of doing it. I do not know how to use Pygame interlinked with it, so please explain.

I was expecting to get my game on the website i am making, didn't work out.

Comment: See [pygame-web](https://github.com/pygame-web)

Answer (score -1):

Exporting from Pygame to anything (EXE, APK, HTML) is always an extremely hard task that most people say you shouldn't even try because its almost easier to remake your game in something that can export more easily. but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36388652/how-to-release-pygame-into-a-webpage) question is very similar and has some answers that look reasonable!